# Google charts rendering poorly when they aren't visible?

Tags: javascript, css, charts, google-visualization

So I have a few pages in a React app, and they're all rendered right off the bat. Flipping between them just changes which ones are marked as `display: none` vs `display: block`. In some of them, I'm rendering Google Charts, like this:

```
export default class DailyAreaChart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="sectionHeader">Earnings per Day</h2>
        <div id="dailyAreaChart" width="908" height="378"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.drawChart();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.drawChart();
  }
  drawChart() {

    let areaData = [['Date', 'Earnings']];
    const data = this.props.data;
    const dates = this.props.dates;
    const niceDates = this.props.niceDates;

    dates.forEach((date, i) => {
      areaData.push([
        niceDates[i],
        Math.round(data[date]*100)/100,
      ]);
    });

    let graphData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(areaData);
    let chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('dailyAreaChart'));
    const options = {
      legend: 'none',
      height: 350,
      chartArea: {'width': '85%', 'height': '75%'},
      fontName: 'Roboto',
      colors: ['#0074D9'],
    }
    chart.draw(graphData, options);

  }
}
```

The issue comes up when a chart is initially rendered when it's inside of a `display: none` div. Whichever ones are displayed on the initial load look fine, but the ones that start hidden aren't full-width. They look like this:

[image: Graph squished to the left.]

If I try to set a `width` property in the options, I can make them full-width, but I run into a whole other issue.

[image: Graph with squished labels.]

I realize that I could re-render the graphs when someone clicks from one page to another, but I'd prefer not to. Right now clicking from one tab to another runs really fast and smooth, rendering graphs each time would slow it down.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here's my code that chooses which one to show:

```
export default class Report extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <div style={{display: (this.props.report==="Today")?"block":"none"}}>
          <Today />
        </div>

        <div style={{display: (this.props.report==="Daily")?"block":"none"}}>
          <Daily />
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can position them offscreen and with opacity: 0. This will let them render correctly and you can show them when you want.

Comment: @andrewngo - How do you recommend positioning them offscreen? I've added the code for how I currently hide/show pages to the main question.

Comment: I used a css class with position: absolute, left: -9999px and opacity: 0. Then I remove that class when I want to show the chart. I'm unfamiliar with React so not sure if you can do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. I've almost got it now. Unfortunately, when I render way off screen, for some reason Google Charts thinks the width of the container is very wide. This is probably something to do with React and Bootstrap though.

Comment: In case anyone ever stumbles upon this, seeing the same issues as me, moving the graph to -99999px from the top instead of the left fixed my width problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I've gotten so far was by changing this:

```
<div style={{display: (this.props.report==="Today")?"block":"none"}}>
   <Today />
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div style={(this.props.report==="Today")?{}:{position: "absolute",top: -99999,padding:"10px"}}>
   <Today />
</div>
```

This hides the div offscreen, but still renders it. I've also seen a good performance boost from doing it this way.